# How do I build a related list against a Files Library (in Lightning)

Tags: lightning, related-list, files, content, libraries

I want in the related tab of a record to have a Library related list shows all the files in a library? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking if a File related list can be added in a Tab on the standard Lightning Record Page in Lightning Experience? Or do you mean to build a custom component?

Comment: If you open the tab for "Files" from the app launcher (9 dots on the left), you will see a thing called libraries. I am asking if there is a way to view the contents of a library in a related list of a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand is that you want to display the "Libraries" section available on the "File" tab in a Tab on a record details. As of today, there's no standard out of the box way to do this. I don't at least see any component available on Lightning App Builder, which you can utilize for this purpose.

I would think this to be expected behavior considering that Libraries are a way to organize your Files which is not associated to any particular record. And that what you see on a record is a specific file associated to that record.

If at all you require one, the only option I see is that you need to create a custom lightning component and use [ContentWorkspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm) to be able to pull all libraries and display that accordingly.

Comment: Seems about right. I've built a component and its quite straight forward actually. Thank you